# Improving performance with large native query SQL/JPA/Hibernate

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate, jpa, caching

My application is currently used by several Spring Batch processes to perform several (native) queries to a database for a span of 2 years, and then iterate through that data to compare with a different set of data to detect patterns between the two. **The 2 year queries (usually 3 of them per batch run) take roughly a minute to retrieve several million results.**

The important thing to note here is that the data **is not changing other than the fact that each day the data start and end date increment by one.** Meaning that if a caching mechanism was in place, each day the query would only need to update the cache with the most recent data, and expunge the oldest days data that falls outside of that 2 year range. And of course the initial query (and query after any time the cache is deleted) would need to execute the whole thing again. Currently there are several batch runs per day executing this query, retrieving the same results each time.

How can I improve my performance here? It looks like the obvious solution is utilizing a cache in some way. I've looked into some mechanisms such as Redis. I don't have much experience in the situation and would appreciate any help on how to get started.

Relevant JPQL query:

```
SELECT a.Account as externalAccount, 
       a.Serial as serialNum, 
       b.Account as toAccount
FROM ITEM_VIEW a, ITEM_VIEW b 
WHERE b.TxnNum = a.TxnNum 
    AND b.[Date] = a.[Date] 
    AND a.[Date] >= :parmEndDate 
    AND a.[Date] <= :parmBeginDate 
    AND a.DBCR = 'D' 
    AND (a.Amount/100) >= :parmAmount 
    AND b.DBCR = 'C'
```

Comment: Almost certainly folks here will want to see the code, but only after you benchmark or profile your code and find out where the hotspots are. You cannot fix performance issues without first knowing what is non-performant.

Comment: The non-performant here is the query itself in this case because it is consistently and unnecessarily querying for such a large amount of data

Comment: Ok, then have you benchmarked/profiled your query? There are lots of tools for doing so. The same comments about knowing what exactly is non-performant still stands. SO is a terrible profiling tool because it can't see your schema. That means you should do some of that legwork so we all have some context to work from.

Comment: Profiling has been done on this query before and I can post results. Maybe I phrased my question wrong but I am not using SO as a profiling tool. I am not trying to improve this query. I am trying to avoid redundantly using the query over and over again for the same information.

Comment: Shouldn't the profile info drive your solution? Maybe start with those findings and position the question in terms of that. My greater comment is that Hibernate is complicated, and often queries that work well directly are terrible when run in other contexts -- and the only way to dig into that is to inspect the code/annotations/schema.

Comment: What kind of data set size are you working with here? Assuming all the columns are indexed I would expect this query to be exceptionally fast. Minor tweak, but perhaps rewrite the `a.Amount` predicate to save some divisions. The query itself should be cached in the database's query cache. If the result set is huge I would think network latency would be the bottleneck before execution speed.

Comment: The table currently has a little over 211,000,000 records in it if that is what you're asking. The query results can be anywhere around 300,000 to several million depending on the params.

Comment: @rb25 Sure that's helpful. At that order of magnitude I would expect this query execution to be like sub-second if indexed properly. What's your result set size? Moving data over the network is of course much more expensive than fetching from disk/memory.

Comment: On the last run, there were 3 queries executed with result sets of size 332327, 4149920, 5797528. Each query took about 50 seconds

Comment: @rb25 Got it. Have you confirmed that `a.Date` is indexed? My expectation is that network throughput is the bottleneck which I'm not sure cache would help unless it's application side. Could you just write the result set to like a delimited text file and subsequently read from there? Or are the consumers distributed?

Comment: @ryachza I'm currently waiting to receive read access for this database to find out about the indexes. Does writing to a text file make more sense than implementing an application level caching solution? Keep in mind that each day, the oldest day's data is not to be used anymore. Meaning that this text file would need to have records removed and added once a day

Comment: @rb25 Caching does make sense to me if you confirm that execution and/or transmission are indeed the bottleneck. If transmission is the bottle neck it needs to be application side otherwise you haven't gained anything. The options of caching in memory versus on disk and flat file versus served totally depends on resources/access patterns/priorities. You could fetch more, once, and partition it application/cache side, cache could be higher frequency add lower frequency remove with a filter incorporated in between. There are a lot of points to refine for your specific situation.